# How to read Messages from Syslog using Java into a String and push them to another Syslog port

Tags: java, syslog

I have a requirement to run a java cron job or something similar, which should continuosly listen and read Syslog messages which are in XML format, convert them into CEF format after reading and push it to another Syslog port.

Trying to find some help in this regard.

Thanks in Advance,

Arul